# Ubuntu 18.04 running on x280 cannot detect fingerprint reader

Tags: thinkpad

I have an x280 with a fingerprint reader.It was initially installed with Windows 10. The fingerprint was working perfectly until I installed ubunut 18.04. `lsusb` doesn't show any fingerprint device. I have checked that it is enabled in the bios. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So far, no working solution exists.
- The lsusb should show `ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc.` which is the fingerprint reader.
- You can follow this Github issue that explains the problem : https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/issues/34
No other project managed to go as far as this.

Answer (score 0):

there is now a solution.
[uunicorn /python-validity](https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity) worked on it for a long time and thanks to them now `ID 06cb:009a Synaptics, Inc.` is usable in Ubuntu (I tested with Ubuntu 20.04)

Basically follow these commands (taken directly from their github):

```
$ sudo apt remove fprintd
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity
...wait a bit...
$ fprintd-enroll
```

If you run into errors (I didn't) you can go to their github. They have a list of solutions for possible errors